# Is there a smarter way to write this RegExp?

Tags: javascript, regex

Consider this regular expression: `/^(B|C|AB|AC|BC|ABC)$/`. It only accepts strings containing `B` or `C` (inclusive or), optionally preceded by `A`. Although it works just fine as it is, listing one by one all accepted strings, it clearly isn't a very scalable solution, especially given that `A`, `B` and `C` may substitute longer phrases. My question is: is there a way to write an equivalent regular expression in which `A`, `B` and `C` only appear once?

Comment: I see code sample slightly contradicts description. is `ACC` still valid? and what's about `ACB`?

Comment: Scalable to what end? What are you ultimately trying to do?

Comment: If you're looking for scalability, why don't you write a function that dynamically generates the regex pattern for you?

Answer (score 1):

`/^(B|C|AB|AC|BC|ABC)$/`

is directly equivalent to

`/^(A(?:BC?|C)|BC?|C)$/`

in which the latter is about 10 times faster.

Comment: Performance is not an issue and I honestly think the listed way is somewhat more legible? At least to me. Thanks for your time anyway.

Comment: @JacopoCosta  - Eventually you lose control of what your matching, better to let a tool handle it for you: http://www.regexformat.com/version7_files/Rx5_ScrnSht01.jpg . . As a side note this regex   `(B|C|AB|AC|BC|ABC)` will never match `BC` or `ABC` without the anchors. This  `(A(?:BC?|C)|BC?|C)` however will.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

`^A?(BC?|C)$`

Comparing to the expression in your question, this matches

B C AB AC ABC

But does not match

A ACB AAB ABA AAC ABCC

Comment: "… in which A, B and C only appear once?" – your regex accepts e.g. `ABCC`.

Comment: You're right. Should use the `?` instead of `*` --> `^A?(BC?|C)$`. I edited the original answer.

Answer (score -1):

`/^(B|C|AB|AC|BC|ABC)$/`

Since `A` is an optional prefix, we can take it out and use `?`:

`/^A?(B|C|BC)$/`

If you want to get rid of the duplication of `B` and `C`, there might be a way with regular expression [subroutines](https://www.regular-expressions.info/subroutine.html). Unfortunately these don't seem to work in JS! How about post-processing after a false match instead?

`/^A?(B?)(C?)$/`

Then check that at least one of the two capturing groups matched:

```js
let re = /^A?(B?)(C?)$/;
for (let str of [
  "A",
  "B",
  "C",
  "AB",
  "AC",
  "ABC",
  "BAC",
  "CBA",
  "AAB",
  "ABBC"
]) {
  let groups = str.match(re);
  let match = (!!groups && (!!groups[1] || !!groups[2]));
  console.log(str, match);
}
```

Comment: This comes the closest to solving my problem, the RegExp itself only has 2 false positives (```'A'``` and ```''```), but I suppose my original worries are confirmed, there is no easy way to express an _inclusive or_ in JS regular expressions. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score -2):

Here we go!

```js
var regex = RegExp('^A{0,1}(BC{0,1}|C)$');
// Good
console.log('GOOD');
console.log(regex.test('AB'));
console.log(regex.test('AC'));
console.log(regex.test('ABC'));
console.log(regex.test('B'));
console.log(regex.test('C'));

// Wrong
console.log('WRONG');
console.log(regex.test('A'));
console.log(regex.test('CB'));
console.log(regex.test('ACB'));
console.log(regex.test('CAB'));
console.log(regex.test('ABX'));
console.log(regex.test('Z'));
```

Comment: I believe the regex in the OP lists *all* the strings that should be accepted, your regex accepts much more (e.g. `ABB`).

Comment: @AurelBílý good poing. Jacopo, could you please clarify this?

Comment: Yeah, I realize this is an oddly specific problem, but only the 6 strings listed should be accepted

Comment: @JacopoCosta thanks for clarification. I will update my answer.